# Typescript template literal types circular constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, template-literals

I'm struggling to find a way of displaying a type parameter in an error message. The idea is to prevent passing dependencies that were already injected, and check this during compile time.

This is how I solved it:

```js
export type TCons<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

export interface Has<K extends string, T> {
  get: (k: K, v: TCons<T>) => T
}

type CombineExclusive<Host, Key extends string, Provider> = <
  P extends Host extends Has<Key, P> ? `${Key} already exists` : Provider
>(
  provider: P
) => Host extends Has<Key, P> ? never : Host & Has<Key, P>

export interface Application {
  withSearchProvider: CombineExclusive<this, "SearchProvider", SearchProvider>
}
```

If used like this:

```js
const liveApplication = (app: Application) =>
  app
    .withSearchProvider(new A())
    .withSearchProvider(new B())
    .withSearchProvider(new A())
```

You will get an error on the last line which looks like this: `SearchProvider already exists`.
I want to improve it a little bit: `SearchProvider A already exists` and here is where I started to struggle:

```js
type CombineExclusive<Host, Key extends string, Provider> = <
  P extends Host extends Has<Key, P> ? `${Key} ${P} already exists` : Provider
>(
  provider: P
) => Host extends Has<Key, P> ? never : Host & Has<Key, P>
```

I cannot reference P in the template literal since it creates a circular constraint. Another way might be to reference "original" P, but I don't know how, or whether it is possible.
So, my task is to create a type constraint which error message displays parameter type P. Any ideas?

Link to ts playground: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCmYBOwAWAFJB7AbgSwBN4loBvAXwChRIYBBMy6aAFwE8AHeALmgCIwfaAF5%20gylRpRoAIUbN2XXnwBGQ0ar4TKleAA8OWJC1ad40ACoBhLADsIAHgsA%20EdFvwA7tAAUAOgDkAHMIXjBbNgBtAF0AShFXCx19Q2NoPFsWYgAzMGBzAAlIBwBpaH0s2wIYCBYkDKCAGktXUiZoIPgWXh8Aa14S5pxeaztHF3jhRO1KRXMbAFsVDPgAUT1QAFcIPBx4BwKsWuaS%20DZyvUrq6Fr62yboTFxCYldRB3b0C6uYQ9rv%20BVX7FU5sZroVwAfmgAAMACSkUHkaBgEBIRAEc76PC1CAw6C8J74IhIdrOHztDjYYnEQmUSauP4mCqA65FRyg8FQ9zwPYkXhM6AAMmg7NKZy5yQMRhMGSySFy%20WgdA4HBAeGAYBYeDs8mgnjwLFQCGQaCJLyQvEWyw86y2Oz2DiNOOafBNKAw1ItfGa7rNXpJzhm1DGJnVexVao1Wp1tjcPjAqt4kfVmu1dgZ7UTHHazD8BqNfs9zxJPg83joPlisVz0HzhuNiA95tL5dkVZrzDzBcbpuLNKQZa8yo70AA9GPykhsCQ5az4AQUfR9ZAUWiMec%20BkAFbwYBZAhaSgT6AASRXmVYWGgqDAe2gCyM5iILDAeBA6TjRvMxBnD-gUBgJ0KJVDcqBYN4nioBqqAXHkJhSDAmrbABx6TsAWAgOqOy6iomwmNsDSmFwthgAs5hfBkrDwAsapauY6ryqi0DAOi9EwGALF4CgmzgCQGH2HUb6ZH4sxmNA1orHaICEXsABMBxHCwJxnACQI3HUDTggGrxuB8zBfCy6mCkZbIghKjzcvCiJnMiCLoMiqJsZiFw4iweIEo8Omksw5KUt5dIMqKSlqWZHIWRC0DQh4fKeYKIpipyllAA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WoJRMm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz no problem) Added playground link and fixed some classes.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnXy6W) meet your needs?  I'm quite confused how you intend the string literal `A` to appear anywhere; you can't write `\`${P}\`` if `P` is not a `string` or something else serializable via template literals.  If you can make that sensible in some way (e.g., maybe assume that every `Provider` will have a string literal property type corresponding to its name? ‍♂️), then the conditional type thing I did should hopefully work.  But I'd rather answer the question without the odd dependency on turning type names into strings.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for answer! This is definitely an option. However I noticed that typename is already printed in the start of the error message anyway and I guess that's good enough for me... Can you post your suggested solution as an answer? I think it can really useful to other people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript sometimes accepts circular references and other times does not.  If you have a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type and can't get a circular reference to be accepted inside a type parameter's [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), you can sometimes move the reference out of the constraint and into a [conditionally typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) function parameter.  That is, from something like this:

```
function orig<T extends F<T>>(param: T) { } // error, circular constraint
```

to something like this:

```
function fixed<T>(param: T extends F<T> ? T : F<T>) { } // okay
```

It's a bit of a weird construction to write `T extends F<T> ? T : F<T>`, but generally speaking the compiler will infer `T` to be the type of `param`.  Therefore if `T extends F<T>` as desired, the function will look like `function fixed<T>(param: T) {}` and there will be no error. On the other hand if `T extends F<T>` is not satisfied, then the function will look like `function fixed<T>(param: F<T>)` and since `param` is of type `T` but not `F<T>`, you'll get an error very similar to the one you get when you violate a generic constraint.

---

In your example, this could be changed to something like:

```
type CombineExclusive<Host, Key extends string, Provider> = <
  P extends Provider
  >(provider: P extends (Host extends Has<Key, P> ? never : unknown) ? P :
    `${Key} of type '${Extract<P, { type: string }>['type']}' already exists`
) => Host extends Has<Key, P> ? never : Host & Has<Key, P>
```

I changed it around a little, but it has the same effect; if `Host extends Has<Key, P>` is true, the this becomes `` P extends unknown ? P : `...` `` which becomes `P` and the call will succeed.  If `Host extends Has<Key, P>` is false, then this becomes `` P extends never ? P : `...` `` which becomes `` `...` `` and the call will fail, with the template literal as part of the error message.

Also note that you cannot serialize `P` to a string via `` `${P}` `` because `P` is not a `string`/`number`/`boolean`/`bigint` (as required by [ms/TS#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)).  So I'm taking `P`, which should have a `string`-valued `type` property, and putting that in the message.

Let's see it in action:

```
const liveApplication = (app: Application) =>
  app
    .withSearchProvider(new A())
    .withSearchProvider(new B())
    .withSearchProvider(new A()) // error 
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// '"SearchProvider of type 'a' already exists"'.(2345)
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QDeUAhgFxTHABOAlvgOZQC+UA-OVbfWZsANFABGtfAFcAtmIgNOUWhQDGtMQHtNAGwiV8nAFBGAZlPyrgTTYc3NWiLLgIlYiJEgAUYSg0oytAgAlHxcAPThWAwM9mYWVjaGpkzYHj5+AUHOeESk8Mg8GMruyKEUEVGaANaUICaqOpTEpADK+gyqABYACrEAbkyECmFGjc2kAILkRlBQoJC0AESUS2hQK0tGHGNNLVAAQjNzCxDLYmvoSxfbJiY4YPbA8+DQCADCtsQe6-gQAO5QLwAOlBflYxFoBhAAG0ALqhVAoBD3bCPBjPFh4BimSiqaAACWacAA0jlXKRBCxWKJCmRZlBWBBgLQvNVaCTRP0gp98N8ymhkbcjKcoJ85CwIABRbCNKTEJj9CBwAmaeiiEkQEDkvJ0RjU0R9TSDYYMFDoOAMno6txGk0KBneMADIYKWjWnC5NxeVX0G2kInfTUgQ0oXh-JWKWgWar4TT-fChXjW6gMuYAAwAJGRg1xNKYXpAoABybMyxh44BwHqiCinAT6ticJAw4unYtwjjFqg6Bj6QjanBMejEdNGREoX3PT0UqCB0la0NFCMjWhTqAAMjnxODobuDyeUCxClx+KgkzAYB0TFUlGstmOUH+TGAXXafm6dtdDFo4rEkplOUFSVOBX2HUQlnfTpehdU0llEKDP1ghQkGFVQvmea8lQvK8bzvJJ1i8ShL1oHDr1ve9E0FBliLANMoGBZ9X0QmDjW-Lw-kBSYvGCYJ6MYl83w6JC2NNDiAUOHi+LmOYBOY4TWPtBhxK4qSoEiaJYkUIwNIAWn0gzDKMwyUAAP3MizTJ0qJJgYVhZAIZ580LaBi0mbthygONngmJhWHwSgxD0eZNCgXx-BkZkRmc0VrJLSCFK-U0oBi14S0obtKF7ftB2wYdgGIJZi2BLwACYAGYABYAFY+KMIA)